# Set operations not working for Custom Object

Tags: c++, set

So I have a custom object called `WaterJug` and I'm getting errors when calling functions on a global `set<WaterJug>`:

This is defined before the class definition:

`set<WaterJug> memo;`

And in one of the methods of my class:

```
for(std::vector<WaterJug>::iterator newJug = newJugs.begin(); newJug != newJugs.end(); ++newJug) {
    const bool is_in = memo.find(newJug); //error here
    if (is_in) {

    }
}
```

Error is: `No matching member function for call to 'find'`

Do I have to implement any interfaces in my custom class for the set operations to work?

Comment: How are you compiling this?  What C++ version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have couple of errors.

1. Wrong argument being passed to `memo.find`.

   ```
   memo.find(newJug) // tpe of newJug is an iterator, not an object.
   ```

   It needs to be

   ```
   memo.find(*newJug)
   ```
2. The return value of `memo.find()` is not a `bool`. It is an iterator. Instead of

   ```
   const bool is_in = memo.find(newJug); //error here
   if (is_in) {
   ```

   use:

   ```
   if ( memo.find(*newJug) != memo.end() )
   ```

Answer (score 0):

[std::set::find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/find/) takes an object, `newJug` is an an iterator, not an object, to access the object "pointed" by the iterator, you need to dereference `newJug`: `*newJug`:

Moreover, `find` returns an iterator, not a `bool`, it returns `end()` iterator of object os not found.

This version of the code will work:

```
for(std::vector<WaterJug>::iterator newJug = newJugs.begin(); newJug != newJugs.end(); ++newJug) {
    const bool is_in = ( memo.find(*newJug) != memo.end() );
    if ( is_in ) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`std::set::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/find) only takes parameter of the `key` type of the set.  When you use `memo.find(newJug)` you are calling `find` with an iterator to a `key` and not a `key`.  You can dereference the iterator to get a key value `memo.find(*newJug);`.

You also have an issue with the fact that you are trying to store the return from find as a `bool` when `find` returns an iterator.  If you want to know if `find` found something then you can rewrite

```
const bool is_in = memo.find(newJug);
```

To

```
const bool is_in = (memo.find(newJug) != memo.end());
```